# Mule:SFTP download connector usage

Tags: mule, mule-studio, mule-component

I have this requirement of downloading multiple files from a server locations temp/folder1/currentdatefolder, temp/folder2/currentdatefolder and temp/folder3/currentdatefolder with file name same in all three directory locations . Do i need to have a composite source of SFTP connector haveing three connector downloading from three directories or only one SFTP connector will be able to download from all three directories . If a single SFTP connector is used do we need to use for each for all three folders.

Answer (score 1):

Composite source with multiple inbound-endpoints or separate flows with individual inbound-endpoints.

Either way you do not need foreach as each File is handled individually as it;s own message.

Answer (score 1):

Ryan's solution is perfectly fine, for those cases where the folders are not well know or variable, you could also use a [service-override](http://forum.mulesoft.org/mulesoft/topics/sftp_recursive_file_transfer) to enable recursivity.